# Trouble loading .csv file into Big Query with hh:mm:ss over 24 hours

Tags: google-bigquery, load.csv

I calculated the difference between two dates with times in a column in XL. I then formatted that column to 37:30:55. I then converted the file to .csv format. Some of the hours exceeded 23:59:59. When I tried to load the .csv file into Big Query I got the error message "failed to create table: Error while reading data, error message: could not parse "24:00:42" as TIME for field ride_length (position 4) starting at location 48115947 with message "Invalid time string 24:00:42"

I was told to format the difference between two dates with times in XL as 37:30:55.

Please advise. TIA

Please see the explanation i posted.